# Py_Initialize() failed when trying to mix c++ and python

Tags: python, c++, hybrid

I was trying to write a tiny program to practice mixing c++ with python, but failed at the very beginning. **`Py_Initialize`** failed. The error message said that:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f5bdd5b6780 (most recent call first):
```

And the code is:

```
#include"Python.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_Finalize();
    return 1;
}
```

**Note** that I have set my **PYTHONHOME** to be:

```
/home/ddyang/anaconda3/
```

Since I am using the python in anaconda.

The result of **`echo $PYTHONHOME`** is good. And when I type python in teriminal, it also says that I am using anaconda's python. And the other programs I worte using python in anaconda work fine as well.
So I am really confusing.

I wrote the code in Eclipse and compiled it successfully. There was no errors during compilation. However, there did exist another error before the problem mentioned above. It said that:

```
home/ddyang/ec-workspace/test-main/Debug/test-main: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I then set a symbolic link and solve this problem, but I did not really know how this actually worked:

```
sudo ln -s /home/ddyang/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.5m.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
```

I am guessing that maybe I haven't really solved the first problem which resulted in the current one.

The environment variable I set in **.bashrc** is:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/ddyang/anaconda3/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin"
alias python='/home/ddyang/anaconda3/bin/python'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64
export PYTHONHOME="/home/ddyang/anaconda3/"
```

----**Update**----

I then added **PYTHONHOME** and **PYTHONPATH** at **`etc/environment`**, the problem above disappeared, however another problem appeared:

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ddyang/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 72, in <module>
 import os
File "/home/ddyang/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 666, in <module>
from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
File "/home/ddyang/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/_collections_abc.py", line 56
async def _coro(): pass
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I believe this problem lies in the situation where I **am using the wrong version python**, not the one in anaconda3(python3.5). However, still when I am in terminal, I type **`python --version`** it says that I am using python 3.5 in anaconda.

The following code may support my guess.

```
ddyang@dd-pc:/usr/local/bin$ ls
charm  cmake  cpack  ctest  uncrustify
ddyang@dd-pc:/usr/local/bin$ python charm
  File "/home/ddyang/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ddyang@dd-pc:/usr/local/bin$ /home/ddyang/anaconda3/bin/python charm
ddyang@dd-pc:/usr/local/bin$ /usr/bin/python3.4 charm
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ddyang/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 72, in   <module>
    import os
  File "/home/ddyang/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 666, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
  File "/home/ddyang/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/_collections_abc.py", line 56
    async def _coro(): pass
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ddyang@dd-pc:/usr/local/bin$ /usr/bin/python2.7 charm
  File "/home/ddyang/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And the python3.4 is the system's default python. It seems that when I am referring to it.